# Generating ip address by randomising last byte in each row in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am taking an input of an ip address. I want to randomise the last byte between the range 0 to 254 of the ip address and print the ip address in each row of the pandas dataframe.
For Example:
The given input ip address is : **'10.10.10.0'**
Expected output:
`>> 10.10.10.5`
`>> 10.10.10.173`
`>> 10.10.10.34`
and so on...
Here is the sample code I used :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
from random import randint

df_header="IPV4_SRC_ADDR"
def func(IPV4_SRC_ADDR= "253.253.253.253", filename=None):
    df = pd.DataFrame(0, index=np.arange(1000), columns=df_header) #generating a dataframe with all initial values as 0

    if(IPV4_SRC_ADDR!="253.253.253.253"):
        IPV4_SRC_ADDR = IPV4_SRC_ADDR.rsplit('.', 1)[0]
        df['IPV4_SRC_ADDR']=IPV4_SRC_ADDR + '.' + str(np.random.randint(0, 254, df.shape[0]))
    else:
        df['IPV4_SRC_ADDR']=IPV4_SRC_ADDR

    if(filename is not None):
        df.to_csv(filename, mode='a', header=False)
    else:
        df.to_csv('output.csv')

if __name__== "__main__":
    generate_netflow(IPV4_SRC_ADDR="10.10.10.0")
```

where, `IPV4_SRC_ADDR` is the variable and `'IPV4_SRC_ADDR'` is the column name.
However, my result using this code is like this:
`"10.10.10.[118 139 117  39 127  11 228 116  15 118 132 217  41 202  99 241 168 240]"`
And each column has this value.
I know I am doing something wrong in `str(np.random.randint(0, 254, df.shape[0]))`.
I think the problem is when I am converting an array to string.

Comment: How is your IP address input stored exactly? Are you saying the input is in the form of a row in pandas, and you want to extract it, take the 4th position and randomize that and reset the IP back into the row? It would really help if you provided a reproducible example

Comment: The input is in the form of a string and I am writing it into a csv file column wise. In this case, the column name is `IPV4_SRC_ADDR`

Comment: `IPV4_SRC_ADDR` is the column that takes the randomized 4th byte yes?

Comment: It stores the output final ip address that is randomised on the last byte

Comment: so this means, there are MULTIPLE input IP addresses yes? How are these MULTIPLE input IP addresses coming from? Are they stored in a list.. or read in using `input()`. I can give you a full solution to it with some sample code. Also, how many randomized 4th byte IP addresses for each IP address input are you looking for?

Comment: I have edited the code, please have a look. Number of lines are 1000 in this case. Hope this helps you to understand :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to get a list of IPv4-addresses.

To achieve this you can use a list comprehension:

```
df['IPV4_SRC_ADDR'] = [IPV4_SRC_ADDR+'.' + str(x) for x in np.random.randint(0,254,df.shape[0])]
```

This combines every random number as string with the given starting string.